# What is the best way to send e-mails to a given email list?

Tags: email

I have a app online and I want the users to subscribe for my new apps. The user were given a form to fill in their emails if they want to subscribe.

After collecting the emails, how do we send out updates? Is there any good service that can do this? The content should be dynamic (like at least putting the user's name in it)

Comment: Does it need to be free?

Comment: @ZachSpencer Doesn't. I can pay for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company uses [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com) it's pretty simple to use, and supports mass emailing with dynamic content .If you have under 2000 subscribers it's free.